# Mount folder into webroot with Lando

Tags: docker, lando

So I have 2 folders next to each other, "cms" and "project-1".
The "project-1" folder contains the lando file.
I'm trying to mount the cms folder inside the webroot in order to create a proxy for it.

[image]

```
name: project-1
recipe: lamp
config:
  webroot: .
proxy:
  site:
    - project-1-site.lndo.site
  cms:
    - project-1-cms.lndo.site
services:
  webserver:
    type: php:7.3
    via: apache:2.4
    ssl: true
  database:
    type: mariadb:10.1.47
  pma:
    type: phpmyadmin
    hosts:
      - database
  site:
    type: php:7.3
    via: apache:2.4
    ssl: true
    webroot: /public
    build_as_root:
      - a2enmod headers
  cms:
    type: php:7.3
    via: apache:2.4
    ssl: true
    webroot: ../cms
    build_as_root:
      - a2enmod headers
```

What would be the best way to achieve this result?
I don't want to move the lando file in the same folder as the "cms" and "project-1" folders.

I have tried the cp command in build_as_root but it seems impossible to target content outside of the folder where the lando file is located.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the drupal7 recipe and mounting an outside folder worked for me as follows:

Assuming the following project folder setup:

- [parent folder]/lando (this has .lando.yml)
- [parent folder]/cms (this has index.php)

The following lando config worked:

```yaml
name: my-project
recipe: drupal7
config:
  webroot: .
services:
  appserver:
    # Keys 'app_mount' and overrides/volumes allow outside lando folder.
    # @see https://docs.lando.dev/compose/config.html
    # @see https://github.com/lando/lando/issues/1487#issuecomment-619093192
    app_mount: delegated
    overrides:
      volumes:
        - "../cms:/app"
```